# mongodb schema for large csv file

Tags: mongodb, schema

I have a csv file with a very large number of rows and I want to store it in mongodb. I need some suggestions while designing schema.

Schema type 1:

```
var CsvSchema = new Schema({
    col1: String, col2: String, col3: String, col4: String //will save each row of csv file as an object.
});
```

Schema type 2:

```
var CsvSchema = new Schema({
    row: [] //will store each row of csv file as array
});
```

I would then need to perform a lot of read operation this data (reporting app).
My assumptions:

- Data store with Schema type 2 will occupy very less space compare to
  type 1.
- I guess read operation in type 1 will be faster then type 2.

Any suggestion which type of schema I should use to store data considering pros and cons of both...

Answer (score 0):

When you save each row as array (schema 2). You'll occupy less space in storage, but indexing and data operations will be more complicated for MongoDB.

It's important to remember that MongoDB just accept, by default, 16MB per document.

I recommend you to read this article about array operations using MongoDB: http://blog.mlab.com/2013/04/thinking-about-arrays-in-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

The primary question when designing a no sql database is: how will you query the data?

Thus, if you only ever need to retrieve complete rows, never need to search for certain fields, and you are reasonably sure that this will never change througout the software lifetime, go ahead and use type 2. But be aware, that this is a querying nightmare.

If you will use the "normal" search operations that everyone expects from a datastore (search all documents where column1 is "x" and column3 is not "y"), go for type 1.